# How can I do "fan out SSO" i.e. have a product (with multiple customers) connect to a single SSO system, which fans requests out to many client SSOs

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

We have an application which supports a single Identity Provider. However we have multiple customers on it and each of these customers wants to point to their own Identity Providers. It would be a significant amount of rework to allow our application to support many providers. We are looking for a solution (open source or commercial) where we can point our application at a single Identity Provider and (presumably based on email address domain) that Identity Provider can route the requests out to a specific clients Identity Provider. Do such solutions exist?

Comment: I am voting to close this as you seem to seek a tool recommendation.

Comment: I'm seeking a solution recommendation - whatever this means!

Comment: What you are looking for is basically IdP Proxy - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19681-01/820-3746/ghgfu/index.html
For open source solution - please explore if Keycloak provides this feature.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's called Home Realm Discovery.

You federate all these other IDP with your IDP.

When the user logs in they get a choice of which IDP to use to log onto.

Most IDP have rules that allow the IDP to be selected seamlessly.